# IPv6 6to4 mechanism

Tags: ipv4, ipv6

I'm not sure if I get the idea of [6to4 mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4).

The way I see it: if we have two IP v6 hosts that would like to communicate and all of the internet was IP v6, there would be no problem.

However, if there's an IPv4 network on the path from IPv6 host A to IPv6 host B, then apparently it's a problem 6to4 tries to solve. But what is this problem exactly? If I send a packet from IPv6 host A to IPv6 host B, then the only issue I can think of is that routers in IPv4 network don't udnerstand IPv6 addresses = no way to route the packet to host B properly. Anything else? I think 6to4 is **not** about allowing IPv6 hosts to 'talk' with IPv4 ones, which is what the article emphasised.

If the above is true, then we would like to somehow convert IPv6 address of host B to an IPv4 address the IPv4 routers can understand - then IPv4 routers will be able to route the packet to host B. But, for some reason, the wikipedia article I linked to says:

> For example, the global IPv4 address 192.0.2.4 has the corresponding
>   6to4 prefix 2002:c000:0204::/48. This gives a prefix length of 48
>   bits, which leaves room for a 16-bit subnet field and 64 bit host
>   addresses within the subnets.

I just don't get it. We want to convert IPv6 address to IPv4 one, but the quote says the opposite!

Ok, but even if we need that, the IPv6 address has 128 bits. The first 48 bits in the conversion above will be 2002:c000:0204::/48, and the rest is for *subnet field and 64 bit host addresses within the subnets* - **what** subnet field and **what** host addresses within what subnets? Could anyone explain what are the remaining 80 bits used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that 6to4 is for allowing IPv6 hosts (actually whole networks of IPv6 hosts) to talk to other IPv6 hosts. It does that by doing automatic tunnelling: putting the IPv6 packet into an IPv4 packet. This is done by a router that has both IPv4 and IPv6. That IPv4 packet can then be transmitted over the IPv4 internet (which doesn't know how to handle IPv6 at all) to another router that has both IPv4 and IPv6. The IPv4 wrapper is taken off, and the IPv6 packet can travel to its destination.

This is just basic tunnelling. What makes 6to4 so special? It is that the IPv4 address of the router is communicated inside the IPv6 prefix. For example: the address between `2002:c000:0204:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` and `2002:c000:0204:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` can be reached by wrapping (encapsulating) the IPv6 packet inside an IPv4 packet and sending that packet to IPv4 address `192.0.2.4` (`c0`=192, `00`=0, `02`=2, `04`=4). That makes it possible for people whose provider doesn't give them IPv6 but does give them a public IPv4 address to get their own IPv6 addresses. With a `/48` you can create 65536 subnets (which are a `/64` each).

The problem occurs when communicating with systems that have 'normal' IPv6 addresses. Such addresses don't have an IPv4 address encoded in the IPv6 address and therefore the 6to4 router doesn't know which IPv4 address to send the packets to. So it has to send them to a 3rd-party relay that is connected to the normal IPv6 internet. The quality of such relays is very unpredictable, and therefore the connectivity to the normal IPv6 internet is often bad. Therefore such deployment of 6to4 is deprecated (see [RFC7526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7526)).

If you want IPv6 access then first complain to your ISP. If they don't want to provide IPv6 then find a decent ISP that does. If you can't get IPv6 from an ISP then you should look at i.e. [tunnelbroker.net](http://tunnelbroker.net). They provide free IPv6 tunnels with proper connectivity. It's not optimal, but it's much much better than unreliable 6to4.

---

Based on the chat discussion some extra information:

6to4 is an obsolete technology. It was meant to give IPv6 addresses and routeability to people whose ISP didn't provide proper IPv6. A quick overview:

- you need a device with a public IPv4 address
- From that IPv6 address you derive a /48 prefix to use with 6to4
- so my address (37.77.56.75) would become 2002:254d:384b::/48
- that prefix can then be used to provision my whole house/business/etc with IPv6
- that is where you need subnetting
- the device with the public IPv4 address is the gateway between my internal IPv6 network and the rest of the IPv6 world
- and your LANs are numbered out of that 2002:....:....::/48 prefix

And that's it basically :)

The problem with 6to4 is that it needs 3rd-party relays on the internet to relay between the IPv4 internet (to which your 6to4 gateway is connected) and the real IPv6 internet. And you usually have no control over which relays are used for your outbound traffic, and you certainly never have control over which relays are used for your inbound traffic. This causes many many problems with reliability. Connectivity to some IPv6 sites may work, to others it may not, or performance is really unpredictable etc etc etc.

So it is therefore better use i.e. [tunnelbroker.net](http://tunnelbroker.net). They provide proper tunnels straight to the real IPv6 internet :)

Comment: _IPv4 address of the router is communicated inside the IPv6 prefix_ - address of what router? The one that is on the path between my IPv6 hosts and sits inside an IPv4 network?

Comment: The one that has a public IPv4 address and provides IPv6 connectivity to your network. You need to have one of those to use 6to4 :)

Comment: In other words, the one that connects IPv6 network and IPv4 network?

Comment: Indeed. PS: a host with a public IPv4 address can of course play router for itself, but often it's the CPE that performs this function

Comment: And the transformation of IPv4 address to IPv6 address is done manually during configuration, like here: http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/15/6to4-ipv6-tunneling/ ?

Comment: Well, it's nothing more than starting with `2002:` and then appending the 32 bits of the IPv4 address in hexadecimal. How that is configured depends on your device. Most CPEs do it automatically, enterprise equipment is usually configured manually. "It depends"

Comment: R3(config-if)# ipv6 address 2002:a00:301::/128 - in this case the tunnel interface has 2002:a00:301 as the first 48 bits of its IPv6 address + 80 zeros at the end. But the last 80 bits are not actually used anywhere, so in fact I could set it to anything I want, as long as the address starts with 2002:a00:301?

Comment: `0a000301` in hexadecimal is `10.0.3.1` in decimal. That is a private RFC1918 address. You cannot use private addresses with 6to4.

Comment: If you would have used a valid address: yes, 6to4 determines the first 48 bits, the other 80 bits are yours to use. Usually you use the next 16 bits for subnetting so you get `/64s`, which gives you 65536 subnets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32553/discussion-between-user4205580-and-sander-steffann).

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/6to4.svg/871px-6to4.svg.png - the hosts using 2002 IPv6 addresses are in the 'IPv4 island' networks in this case, right? That's the last thing I'd like to clarify.

Comment: I think you mean the IPv6 islands on the left and right. Yes

Comment: Yeah, plus I think that picture is a bit misleading - the "2002::/16" label by the 6to4 relay router - someone could understand that as an address of the interface - AFAIK it's there to mean that packets with source IP starting with that prefix are routed to this router.

Comment: Yes, that's what a prefix is :)

Comment: BTW Cisco is using a private IPv4 address in 6to4 in their official docs example.. (see at the bottom) and as you mentioned, it's not allowed. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/interface/configuration/xe-3s/ir-xe-3s-book/ip6-6to4-tunls-xe.html

Comment: "They provide free IPv6 tunnels with proper connectivity" no, they provide free IPv6 tunnels with limited connectivity due to a combination of deliberate restrictions and a longstanding peering dispute.

Comment: @PeterGreen They really did try, but Cogent seems very stubborn: http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/sites/datacenterknowledge.com/files/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Hurricane-Cake.jpg

Comment: They could use transit to reach cogent on ipv6 just as they do on IPv4 but they are more interested in using the IPv6 transition to muscle their way to Teir 1 status than they are in providing their customers with access to the whole IPv6 Internet.